# Delay rendering in jinja2

Tags: django-templates, jinja2

I'm a recent convert to jinja2 from django templates, up until now I haven't had much trouble porting our existing templates, but now I'm tasked with converting our custom django templatetags. The one I'm having trouble with is a tag for creating a menu like structure which looks something like:

```
{% createmenu mainmenu %}
    <!-- syntax: menuitem url-name-to-resolve <url-args> <url-kwargs> "Url Label" -->
    {% menuitem main-url-name 'Home' %}
    {% menuitem some-other-url-name obj.foo obj.bar 'Page2' %}
    {% if some_condition %}
        {% menuitem some-other-url-name obj.foo obj.bar 'Page2' %}
    {% endif %}
{% menutemplate %}
    <li class="
       {% if menu.is_selected %}selected{% endif %}
       {% if menu.is_first %}first{% endif %}
       {% if menu.is_last %}last{% endif %}">
       {% if menu.is_active %}
           <a href="{{menu.url}}">{{menu.label}}</a>
       {% else %}
           <span class="inactive">{{menu.label}}</span>
       {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endcreatemenu %}
```

The behaviour of this makes setting classes on the menu items much more simple, for example, the menu knows if it's the first or last in the list at render time, so if I surround a menu item in an if condition it may change whether it, or other nodes, are the first or last to be displayed.

Now to jinja. I've tried both contextfunctions, extensions, and macros but I can't seem to get the same behaviour because I don't know how to delay the rendering of the menu items until after I know which ones are going to be rendered. At the moment I'm completely stuck on how to continue, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What was wrong with a Jinja template calling a Python function?  What didn't work?  What problem did you have?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and sorry for my delayed. The problem is that jinja renders all the nodes as it processes them. So the AST looks something like: `MENU[ MENUITEM, MENUITEM, IF[ MENUITEM]]` When it's rendered how do I know if the third or second menuitem is the last one to be rendered? In my django version I did something hacky; I render it (without displaying) and count how many menuitems are rendered, then I call render again now knowing which item is the last. I'm unsure how to do this in jinja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the built-in [`loop`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#for) variable's `first` and `last` attriubtes:

```
{% for item in menu_items %}
<li class="
{%- if loop.first %}first{% endif -%}
{%- if loop.last %}last{% endif -%}">
{# The remainder of your conditions and rendering go here #}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I had considered something like that, unfortunately the first/last function have knowing if the menu item is first or last. It could be that the last item in the menu list isn't rendered at all forcing the n-1 item to be the last visible.

Comment: @Richard - okay, I have to admit to being stumped now - is `menu_items` a list or is it some other kind of data structure entirely?

Comment: It's not really a data structure per se. As my original post showed, they're defined in the template.

Comment: @Richard - so, to make sure I understand you right - the template has all the menu items defined in it - but some of the elements may be hidden depending on the state of local variables (`some_condition`)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'm beginning to think that what I'd like to do isn't possible with jinja, that being said, I have an idea for a work around :- precreate two <li>s for the first and last in the list.

Comment: @Richard - stumbled across the answer - `loop.first` and `loop.last` -- see http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#for - I've updated my answer accordingly!